# Why aren't keystroke numbers working with lowercase alphabet?

Tags: java, keystroke

I'm still relatively new when it comes to keystroke. When I convert a character to a integer then try to keyPress it using robot, it doesn't print out lower case letters, it prints out uppercase letters to lowercase ones.

I tried running the code by changing the input into all-caps (using toUpperCase), which worked, but the code doesn't print out uppercase letters.

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class typeWriter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            String text6 = scan.nextLine();
            String text = text6.toUpperCase();
            char[] text1 = text.toCharArray();
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            int[] Charkey= new int[text1.length];
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(scan.nextInt());
            for(int i = 0; i<text1.length; i++) {
                Charkey[i]=(int) text1[i];
            }
            for(int y = 0; y<text1.length; y++) {
                robot.keyPress(Charkey[y]);
                robot.keyRelease(Charkey[y]);
            }
        } catch (AWTException e) {

        }

    }
}
```

When I input "Hello", I expect it to type out "Hello", but it types out "h5/" instead (without the toUpperCase modifier). If I change the string to all-caps, it prints out the correct word, but all in lowercase. What should I do?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `KeyStroke`, this methods are used to simulate a **key** being pressed/released on the keyboard and expect one of the keycodes defined in [KeyEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) (e.g.`KeyEvent_VK_H` for the `H` key) if this generates an uppercse or lowercase depends on CapsLock state or/and if the Shift key is being pressed (e.g.2 `e` = 101 = 0x65 = `VK_NUMPAD5`). It is almost a *coincidence* (not really) that `VK_A`-`VK-Z`, that is, keys `A` to `Z` have the same code as ASCII `'A'`-`'Z'`.

Comment: What you should do? depends on what you want done... maybe use the uppercase of input characters (as these map to the corresponding key code) and call `keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT)` and `keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT)` before and after pressing the desired key to obtain uppercase  letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somewhat found an answer. To those with the same problem, this might not be the best nor most efficient way to do this, but I made a 2nd array made of the original values, and in the for loop I added an if statement, stating if the original set of values in this certain index is between 65 and 90, It will stimulate a shift key press and the actual key press.